# How to host net.tcp wcf service correctly

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp

WCF and it's configuration sometime will make me kill myself.

I have a windows service with plugins and one of the plugins is WCF net.tcp duplex service (with callbacks). It worked well until i tried to turn it into "plugin", so all configs were cool. Now i can't host it correctly (i cannot add service reference to it from my external project). First of all, i can't feed config to this service, because config is not in app.config or something like this, but in .config file in folder with WCF service dlls. I found some pieces of code, like this:

```
protected override void ApplyConfiguration()
    {
        string configFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(AssemblyDirectory, CONFIG_FOLDER_NAME,
    String.Format("{0}.config", this.Description.Name));

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(configFilename) || !System.IO.File.Exists(configFilename))
            base.ApplyConfiguration();
        else
            LoadConfigFromCustomLocation(configFilename);
    }

private void LoadConfigFromCustomLocation(string configFilename)
    {
        var filemap = new System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = configFilename };
        System.Configuration.Configuration config =
            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration
            (filemap,
             System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        var serviceModel = System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(config);
        bool loaded = false;
        foreach (System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceElement se in serviceModel.Services.Services)
        {
            if (!loaded)
                if (se.Name == this.Description.ConfigurationName)
                {
                    base.LoadConfigurationSection(se);
                    loaded = true;
                }
        }

        if (!loaded)
            throw new ArgumentException("ServiceElement doesn't exist");
    }
```

But they don't work. So i tried to define settings programmatically, like this:

```
var baseUri = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:1488/");
var serviceUrl = "ClientService";
var serviceUri = new Uri(baseUri, serviceUrl);
//var binding = new NetTcpBinding();
BindingElement bindingElement = new TcpTransportBindingElement();
var binding = new CustomBinding(bindingElement);
using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ClientService), serviceUri /*Specify full URL here*/))
{
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = false /*Do not specify URL at all*/});
host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>().IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;

host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IClientService), binding, "net.tcp://localhost:228/LinProgWebServer/ClientService" 
var metadataBehavior = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
if (metadataBehavior == null)
{
metadataBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(metadataBehavior);
}
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), binding, "MEX");

Console.WriteLine("Started service on cotnract {0}, ready for anything", typeof(IClientService).FullName);

host.Open();
_ResetEvent.WaitOne();
}
```

Well, netstat says that something listens my ports, but i still can't add service reference. My mind totally blows. Can you please help me?

I'll be gratefull for any help

Comment: It sounds like you're hosting it just fine, but the problem is adding a reference on the client side. You may have to manually configure the client, either programatically or in its app.config. It's been awhile since I've done this, so sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: @JonB, the trouble is that i'll need to add reference via VS in future. Maybe, i publish service metadata in wrong way?